# Updating position of fixed element on scroll event on unresponsive page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large page running a lot of javascript which also contains a fixed position floating element. The floating element updates its position based on the user's current scroll position, via a function which fires on the scroll event.

The issue I am having is that due to the size and complexity of the page, there is a delay before the code in the scroll event is executed, and this causes the fixed element to noticeably jump when scrolling quickly or using the mouse wheel.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jorsgj2b/1/ (The use of setTimeout simulates the delay in executing the function on the real page.)

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="float"></div>

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #787878;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1400px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.float {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 233px;
    right: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        setTimeout(updateFloat, 50);        
    });
});

var updateFloat = function() {
    var mainTop = $('.main').offset().top;
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var floatOffset = 25;
    var newTop = (scrollPos > mainTop) 
        ? floatOffset + 'px' 
        : mainTop + floatOffset - scrollPos + 'px';

    $('.float').css('top', newTop);;
}
```

I am at a bit of a loss as to how to resolve this. I have tried updating the margin instead of top position, as well as switching between absolute and fixed positioning. Perhaps there is a way to use css transitions to help, however I haven't managed to get them to work here.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: On your live page, do you call `updateFloat()` without the timeout like this?:  `$(window).scroll(updateFloat);`

Comment: Yes, the setTimout is only for the jsfiddle demo to simulate the live page delay.

Comment: And is your posted code the only code that runs while you're scrolling?

Comment: There is some other code that runs on scroll - unfortunately I am not able to modify or remove it. I expect this is what is causing the delay.

Comment: I'm sure that's the problem.  The scroll event runs repeatedly while the window is scrolling. That shouldn't be a problem with your posted code.  Does your missing code need to run repeatedly while the window is scrolling?

Comment: Minimizing jQuery in the scroll event would help.  Here's a version that simplifies `updateFloat()` and doesn't use jQuery in the function:  http://jsfiddle.net/0m7k3exy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You might add `position: sticky` to your css to that the stickiness is done by browsers that support it (only Firefox and Safari according to caniuse.com).

You'll always be limited to the fidelity of the scroll events so you may always see a bit of a delay, but you could improve things a little by caching values instead of looking them up each time updateFloat() is called. For example

```
var mainElement = $('.main');
var windowElement = $(window);
var floatElement = $('.float');

var updateFloat = function() {
    var mainTop = mainElement.offset().top;
    var scrollPos = windowElement.scrollTop();
    var floatOffset = 25;
    var newTop = (scrollPos > mainTop) 
        ? floatOffset + 'px' 
        : mainTop + floatOffset - scrollPos + 'px';

    floatElement.css('top', newTop);
}
```

The problem might also be related to browser trying to re-layout the page because the .float element is in the same render layer as the other divs. You can fix that by adding a style that tells the browser to put the .float element in its own render layer (resulting in much faster rendering due to GPU compositing). The most common trick is to add `transform: translateZ(0);` to your style, but there's also a proposed style [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) that is supported by several browsers. So you should update your css like this

```
.float {
    will-change: scroll-position;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 233px;
    right: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Note that adding render layers increases memory usage so don't go overboard with it. It also sometimes impacts other features, like anti-aliasing of text.